# Const arrays and arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, constants

when I pass a const int array to a function that gets int array there is compiler error but 
when I pass an  int array to a function that gets const int array its OK.

why is this happening? I thought mispassing argument is compiler error.

Comment: Can we see some of your code?

Comment: it is a general question.but you can try it, visual studio compiler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not doing something you're allowed to do is fine.

Doing something you're not allowed to do is not fine.

Comment: Let's take it in two steps: Step 1: If i take a constant array to a function that accepts a variable array, it's error: you can't change something that is constant. Step 2: If I pass a variable array to a function that accepts contant arrays it's ok, doesn't matter the array is variable, i'm not gonna change it.